# Group rows by attributes

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I have a data frame containing data about student lateness to various classes. Each row contains data about a late student and his class: date and time of the class, name of the class, class size, number of minutes late, and the gender of the student. In order to get the total percentage of late students for all classes, I need to count the number of rows (late students) and compare that with the total number of students that attended class.

I can't simply sum the class sizes for all of the rows; that would count the students of a given class several times, once for each late student in the class. Instead, I need to count each class size only once for each meeting of the class.

#### Example

Key: minutes late, class name, students in attendance, gender of tardy student, minutes late.

```
11/12/10 Stats 30 M 1
11/12/10 Stats 30 M 1
11/12/10 Stats 30 M 1
11/15/10 Stats 40 F 3
11/15/10 Stats 40 F 3
11/15/10 Stats 40 F 3
11/16/10 Radar 22 M 2
11/16/10 Radar 22 M 2
11/16/10 Radar 22 M 2
11/16/10 Radar 22 M 2
11/16/10 Radar 22 M 2
```

In this case, there are three different class meetings and 11 late students. How could I make sure each class meeting's class size is only counted once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, this is easier to do with the plyr package, rather than tapply or by because it understands what amounts to a multivariate grouping.  For instance:

`ddply(df, .(DATE,CLASS), transform, PERCENT_LATE=length(MINUTES.LATE)/CLASS.SIZE))`

The argument to length here can be any of the column names. ddply will split your dataframe for each combination of DATE and CLASS factor levels.  The number of rows in each mini dataframe should then correspond to how many late students there were (since there is an entry for each late student).  That is where the length(any variable) comes in.  Divide it by the class size column for the fraction.

Comment: nice answer (+1). I'm new to the plyr package. Is there a way to use plyr (i.e. modify your answer) to give just the output aggregated to the class/date level, as per my answer? My answer involves several steps but gives (IHMO ;-) neater output. Your answer is succinct and to the point, but the output contains redundant replication of data. [This isn't a dig - I am genuinely interested if plyr can do this more simply than my answer.]

Comment: @Gavin - the function `summarise` is probably what you are looking for here. From the help page "Summarise works in an analagous way to transform, except instead of adding columns to an existing data frame, it creates a new one."

Comment: Thanks Chase, for the comment and your answer below. When I get out from under the pile on my desk I must take a closer look at plyr.

Comment: @Gavin - another option that may be more clear would be to wrap a `unique()` around the answer from @frannkc

Answer (score 1):

Different functions for sum number late and class size . Need to use a "paste" strategy to create unique combo's of data and class name:

```
>  sum_late <- tapply( tst$V5, paste(tst$V1, tst$V2, sep="_"), length)
>  csize <- tapply( tst$V3, paste(tst$V1, tst$V2, sep="_"), head,1)
> pct_late <- 100*sum_late/csize
> pct_late
11/12/10_Stats 11/15/10_Stats 11/16/10_Radar 
      10.00000        7.50000       22.72727
```

Or with aggregate:

```
>  dfcount <- aggregate( tst$V5, list(tst$V1, tst$V2), length)
> dfcount$pct <- 100*aggregate( tst$V5, list(tst$V1, tst$V2), length)$x/aggregate( tst$V3, list(tst$V1, tst$V2), head,1)$x
> dfcount
   Group.1 Group.2 x      pct
1 11/16/10   Radar 5 22.72727
2 11/12/10   Stats 3 10.00000
3 11/15/10   Stats 3  7.50000
```

Comment: Note that the 5th column (`tst$V5` in your example) is the number of *minutes* late that each student was, not the number of students late. As such, you want `length` not `sum` in your `tapply` call. Note that there are 11 late students and your result suggests 22 late students.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** My solution can be made a lot simpler by computing the trivial % late on a *per row* basis first, then use `aggregate()` to sum these percentages by Date and Class:

```
> df2 <- within(df, pcLate <- 100 * (1 / Size)) 
> df2
         Date Class Size Sex MinsLate   pcLate
1  2010-11-12 Stats   30   M        1 3.333333
2  2010-11-12 Stats   30   M        1 3.333333
3  2010-11-12 Stats   30   M        1 3.333333
4  2010-11-15 Stats   40   F        3 2.500000
5  2010-11-15 Stats   40   F        3 2.500000
6  2010-11-15 Stats   40   F        3 2.500000
7  2010-11-16 Radar   22   M        2 4.545455
8  2010-11-16 Radar   22   M        2 4.545455
9  2010-11-16 Radar   22   M        2 4.545455
10 2010-11-16 Radar   22   M        2 4.545455
11 2010-11-16 Radar   22   M        2 4.545455
> with(df2, aggregate(pcLate, by = list(Date = Date, Class = Class), sum))
        Date Class        x
1 2010-11-16 Radar 22.72727
2 2010-11-12 Stats 10.00000
3 2010-11-15 Stats  7.50000
```

---

**Original Answer:**

Assuming `df` contains the example data you provide, we can do this in a couple of steps using `aggregate()`

First, grab the number of late students per class:

```
summ <- with(df, aggregate(MinsLate, by = list(Date = Date, Class = Class),
                           FUN = length))
names(summ)[3] <- "nLate"
```

Which gives us this starting point

```
> head(summ)
        Date Class nLate
1 2010-11-16 Radar     5
2 2010-11-12 Stats     3
3 2010-11-15 Stats     3
```

Then form the class sizes:

```
summ$Size <- with(df, aggregate(Size, by = list(Date = Date, Class = Class),
                                FUN = unique)$x)
```

Which gets us to here:

```
> head(summ)
        Date Class nLate Size
1 2010-11-16 Radar     5   22
2 2010-11-12 Stats     3   30
3 2010-11-15 Stats     3   40
```

Then compute the percentage late:

```
summ <- within(summ, pcLate <- 100 * (nLate / Size))
```

Which results in:

```
> head(summ)
        Date Class nLate Size   pcLate
1 2010-11-16 Radar     5   22 22.72727
2 2010-11-12 Stats     3   30 10.00000
3 2010-11-15 Stats     3   40  7.50000
```

If you need to do this a lot, wrap it into a function

```
tardiness <- function(df) {
    out <- with(df, aggregate(MinsLate, by = list(Date = Date, Class = Class),
                              FUN = length))
    names(out)[3] <- "nLate"
    out$Size <- with(df, aggregate(Size, by = list(Date = Date, Class = Class),
                                   FUN = unique)$x)
    out <- within(out, pcLate <- 100 * (nLate / Size))
    out
}
```

this does all the steps for us:

```
> tardiness(df)
        Date Class nLate Size   pcLate
1 2010-11-16 Radar     5   22 22.72727
2 2010-11-12 Stats     3   30 10.00000
3 2010-11-15 Stats     3   40  7.50000
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow on @Gavin's comment re: the redundant output, using summarise:

```
df.out <- ddply(x, .(DATE, CLASS), summarise    
    , NLATE = length(c(DATE, CLASS)) / 2
    , SIZE = unique(CLASS.SIZE)
    , PCLATE = 100 * (length(c(DATE, CLASS)) / 2 )/ unique(CLASS.SIZE)
    )
> df.out
      DATE CLASS NLATE SIZE PCLATE
1 11/12/10 Stats     3   30  10.00
2 11/15/10 Stats     3   40   7.50
3 11/16/10 Radar     5   22  22.73
```